# Как посчитать количество одинаковых элементов в массиве js

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Дан список тегов.

```js
const arr = ['li', 'span', 'div', 'span', 'h3', 'a', 'div', 'span', 'a', 'li', 'div', 'div']
```

С помощью цикла посчитать каких тегов сколько штук. В консоли результат должен вывестись как объект. Далее отсортировать полученный объект от большего к меньшему, то есть на первом месте должен быть тег, который чаще всего встречается в массиве.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478316/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc)

Comment: > Далее отсортировать полученный объект от большего к меньшему

Объект не сортируется по ключам.

Comment: @ksa, не то, чтобы совсем не "сортируется"

Comment: @Grundy, и как же объект сортируется? Или у нас с тобой разные "взгляды" на сортировку...

Comment: @ksa, [По какому принципу цикл FOR IN обходит массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606082/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, как сортируется объект? Это простой вопрос. Цикл пускай "ходит" по своим правилам.

Comment: @ksa, именно поэтому "сортируется" и было в кавычках. Неважно как хранится внутри, важно только то, как это отображается.